# How can I add share buttons (twitter, Facebook) to Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using the title attribute hack to add html elements under the media (videos in my case) fo the fancybox popover.

View

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/blahblah?rel=0"
            title="
                <span class='vote_count'>345</span> votes
                <a href='#' method='post' onclick=&quot;vote_up('/videos/vote?id=2', 'blahblah'); return false;&quot; remote='true'><img alt='Vote' src='/images/vote_thumb.png', class='vote_thumb'></a>
                <span class='share'>
                    <a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='/videos/2' data-hashtags='PrettyDarnFunny'>Tweet</a>
                    <div class='fb-like' data-href='/videos/2' data-send='false' data-layout='button_count' data-width='450' data-show-faces='false' data-font='lucida grande'></div>
                </span>
            ">
    <%= image_fu video.keyframe, nil %>
</a>
```

Unobtrusive Javascript

```
// Tweet this
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");

// Like this
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

While this is a nice hack the twitter and facebook buttons aren't being replaced correctly. I'm sure it has some thing to do with how fancybox inserts them into new DOM element (fancy box) as they work on the page but not the fancybox popover.

I'm willing to try other solutions as the title attribute hack is well… hackish.

Comment: Does wrapping the entire title contents with another element like span or div help?

Comment: That didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean they're not be "replaced" correctly?

Comment: I updated the post with the javascript. Essentially it looks for the elements in the view and pulls in its own buttons and scripts.